# Why I can not cast?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public abstrct class Item
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Music : Item
{
    public double Price {get;set;} 
}

public class Game : Item
{
  public string Image {get;set;}
}

public class Inventory
{

private IList<Item> _games;
private IList<Item> _musics;

public Inventory()
{
  _games = new List<Item>();
  _musics = new List<Item>();
}

public void Add<T>(T item) where T : Item
{
if(typeof(T) == typeof(Game))
{
    _game.add(item);
}
if(typeof(T) == typeof(Music))
{
    _muisc.add(item);
}


public List<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : Item
{
  return (List<T>) _muiscs;
}

class Porgram
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
   var music1 = new Music(){ Name ="aa", Price = 10};
   var Music2 = new Music() { Name ="bb", price = 20 };

inventory.add(music1);
inventory.add(music2);


List<Music> myMusics = inventory.GetCollection<Music>();


}
```

The code will compile but it will throw exception when try to Call Get Collection method.

I am not sure really why?  I am guess i am using generic incorrect.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: How does `return (List<T>) _muiscs;` compile? Or `_muisc.add(item);`? Or `public abstrct class Item`?

Comment: Your Inventory class should declare a generic type that extends Item.

Comment: I can not copy and paste my code there are maybe a few typo.

Comment: ...how can you not copy and paste your code?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? Covariance and contravariance for generics are not supported before C# 4.0.

Comment: justderb what do you mean? can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List<Item> cannot be cast to a List<Music>. While Music is a subclass of Item, generic types do not follow the same inheritance pattern as their collection type. The simplest way to fix your code would be to replace the cast in your GetCollection method with a call to the Linq extension method cast, followed by ToList. That said, I think your entire class could be redesigned to handle this sort of inheritence better.

So, your GetCollection method looks like this:

```
public List<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : Item
{
    return _musics.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Music : Item
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Game : Item
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory<E> where E : Item
{

    private IList<E> _games;
    private IList<E> _musics;

    public Inventory()
    {
        _games = new List<E>();
        _musics = new List<E>();
    }

    public void Add(E item)
    {
        if (typeof(E) == typeof(Game))
        {
            _games.Add(item);
        }
        if (typeof(E) == typeof(Music))
        {
            _musics.Add(item);
        }
    }


    public List<E> GetCollection()
    {
        return _musics;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Inventory<Item> inventory = new Inventory<Item>();
        var music1 = new Music() { Name = "aa", Price = 10 };
        var music2 = new Music() { Name = "bb", Price = 20 };

        inventory.Add(music1);
        inventory.Add(music2);


        List<Item> myMusics = inventory.GetCollection();


    }
}
```

You need to declare your Inventory class to be generic where it takes in a class that extend `Item`

Also: It looks like you wrote the code, and didn't copy and paste it... I don't know why you did that...

Comment: <scary-thought>My guess is this was an attempt to obfuscate something he's got in a production system.</scary-thought>

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your GetCollection method as

```
public List <T> GetCollection<T>() where T :Item
        {

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Game))
            {
                return _games.Cast<T>().ToList();
            }
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Music))
            {
                return _musics.Cast<T>().ToList(); ;
            }
        return null;
        }
```